# Как n-ое кол-во чисел, записанные по порядку, разбить n-ое кол-во строк? (Без использования массива) C++

Tags: c++

Сначала вводится с клавиатуры кол-во чисел. Далее с помощью цикла for выводятся рандомные значения в диапазоне от -100 до 100 на экран. Получается набор рандомных чисел, записанный в одну строку. Но мне нужно, чтобы эти числа разбились на кол-во строк, которое также рандомно выбирается в диапазоне от 1 до 10. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Если вы знаете количество чисел N, и количество строк M, то на одну строку приходится N/M чисел + N%M чисел разбросайте по M строкам как хотите... Например, в первые строки по одному.

Comment: окей, это понятно, а каким образом мне реализовать разбиение на строки?

Comment: Как только вывели нужное количество чисел - так сразу выводите `"\n"` - переход на новую строку...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то типа

```
void outs(int N, int M)
{
    int cnt = N/M, rem = N%M;
    for(int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = cnt+(rem ? rem--, 1 : 0) ; j > 0; --j)
            cout << rand()%201-100 << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```